# Disable gnome-panel launcher (Alt+F2)

Tags: unity, gnome-panel, launcher

I'm running Unity and a `gnome-panel` panel at the bottom at the same time. Is there a way to disable the `gnome-panel`'s  launcher? At the moment, both Unity's and `gnome-panel`'s launcher pop up when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable Gnome Panel launcher using Gnome lockdown feature.

Execute this command:

```
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /desktop/gnome/lockdown/disable_command_line true
```

(You can inspect this option using `gconf-editor`) While Unity will ignore this setting, Gnome launcher will be effectively disabled.

Comment: Alternativly, I could have just selected or deleted the shortcut for the gnome-panel launcher, the shortcut for the unity launcher is set in compizconfig-settings-manager.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to reconfigure the shortcut for gnome-panel launcher. Run

```
gnome-keybinding-properties
```

and then, in the Desktop section, you'll see something like "Show the dialog box 'Launch an application' from panel" (sorry I don't know the translation in english) and change the keybord shortcut.

Comment: If I change the keyboard shortcut, the unity launcher will also not show. I'm looking for away to disable the gnome-panel launcher but keep the unity one.

Answer (score -1):

`killall -9 gnome-panel`

Should work

Comment: I want to keep my gnome-panel running, i just don't want the launcher. And if you killall , it just reloads :)